# Method overloading in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, polymorphism, overloading

I came across this problem while I was trying to customize one of the 3rd party plugins we use in our web application.
We tend to not update the core plugin file just to make sure we don't run into issues when we upgrade 3rd party plugins. Best way to avoid this is either extend existing functionality with new set of methods or to override existing plugin methods outside the main plugin file.

One of the plugin I tried to apply this approach was written in an unusual way where it defined all methods in an object outside main plugin function.

So my question is how do we Extend or more likely Overload one of the methods (validateFields, showErrorMsg) of valEngine plugin without updating plugin code.

Here is a JS Fiddle with a rough prototype.
http://jsfiddle.net/g9Ng9/

```
// Can't update any of this.
(function($) {

  "use strict";

  var methods = {
    validateFields: function() {
        console.log('I perform validation of fields!');
    },
    showErrorMsg: function() {
        console.log('I log error messages');
    }
  };

  $.fn.valEngine = function() {
    console.log('I access methods within method object!');
    methods.validateFields();
    methods.showErrorMsg();
  };
})(jQuery);
// Can't update any of this.


// Your code goes here
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Just updated my writeup as I realized its not descriptive enough.

Comment: you may need to add one line to the plugin like this [http://jsfiddle.net/g9Ng9/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/g9Ng9/1/)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe thanks. thats an option If at all there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get this done as the whole point of keeping those methods outside plugin definition is to keep them private.

So in order to overload the methods object method like 'validateFields' we need to amend the core plugin file in some form.

Something similar to what Abraham Uribe mentioned here in his JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9Ng9/1/

// Can't update any of this.
(function($) {

```
"use strict";

var methods = {
    validateFields: function() {
        console.log('I perform validation of fields!');
    },
    showErrorMsg: function() {
        console.log('I log error messages');
    }
};

$.fn.valEngine = function() {
    console.log('I access methods within method object!');
    methods.validateFields();
    methods.showErrorMsg();
};

$.fn.valEngine.methods=methods;
});
$().valEngine();
$.fn.valEngine.methods.validateFields=function(){
  console.log("validateFields");
};

$().valEngine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend or overload jQuery methods by using [extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) method.

A simple example would be

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
validateFields: function() {

 // your custom code here   
}    
});
```

I am not sure but, the namespace in your case would be  `jQuery.fn.ValEngine`.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. But the methods are not part of $.fn object. They are defined within same namespace.

Comment: Then try changing the namespace.

Comment: @MelwynFurtado I think `jQuery.fn.ValEngine` would be namespace in your case.

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide a fiddle link ? methods I am trying to override are not part of the plugin at all.